# Laravel - Can't get .pem public key data from .env file

Tags: php, laravel

I have an webapp built with Laravel and i need to use a public key from a .pem file to verify some data. The key is kept in the .env file and retrieved via `config/app.php` with the `env()` helper. Since the .pem key needs to be on separate lines with specific length i use \n characters to keep the key on one line. Problem is that when i use the \n characters the variable is not cached and i cannot access it. When i remove the \n characters i can retrieve the variable but the `openssl_get_privatekey($key);` returns false. What am i doing wrong? Is this a Laravel or some general PHP issue?

Comment: Put the pem in actual file and store it on server; put filepath to the file in the .env.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP's dotenv package does not seem to support multi-line environment variables.

You should ideally keep your .pem file as a file and reference it by path like e.g.:

```
PEM_FILE=/path/to/file.pem
```

and in the config:

```
return [
    //...
    "key" => file_get_contents(env('PEM_FILE'))
```

This makes sense since generally certificates should generally go in the dedicated certificates path on the server. If you cache the config then the actual contents of the .pem file are only read once on deployment.

However if you must put it in dotenv then you can do:

In .env

```
PEM_KEY="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n…\n-----END DSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
```

In configs:

```
return [
    //...
    "key" => str_replace("\\n", "\n", env('PEM_KEY')),
```

Since the key is generally base64 I don't think there's a chance `\n` would naturally occur inside a .pem file.

Comment: First of all, thank you for a very thorough answer. I should have been a bit more precise with my question. The second part of your answer is what i'm trying to do at the moment and it doesn't work. Right after i add the `\n` it stops working. But i'll try the first part and see if that works.

Comment: I tried the first part and it works until i actually need to use it, the `openssl_get_privatekey($key)` still returns false.

Comment: According to [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-get-private.php) you can try setting `PEM_FILE="file://path/to/file.pem"` and having openssl read it directly from the file via `openssl_get_privatekey(env('PEM_FILE'))`. If that doesn't work then maybe there's something wrong with the actual key file

Comment: Still not working. If you don't mind you can check it out for yourself. The key is accessible here and is public: https://klient.liisi.ee/static/payment_link_doc/_downloads/live-ipizza-2016.pem